# How to convert the following time format to a time formatted string (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading the following kind of data from a file. The time is written like this there:

[image: Forat of time I wish to convert]

Is there a way I can convert the above string to the format 'HH:MM:SS'.I do not want a time object.  It should return me a string.

I tried stripping the letters H and M but some data fields do not have H specified with them, so I could not figure out any other way to solve this problem.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What exactly did you try, and at which point did it fail to produce the expected result? Please share your code with sample input and expected vs actual output.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
try:
    print(datetime.strptime("10H5M", "%HH%MM").strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
except ValueError:
    try:
        print(datetime.strptime("10H", "%HH").strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    except ValueError:
        print(datetime.strptime("5M", "%MM").strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

view the formatting [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), you could also use the str.find method instead of using try and except. Note the find method return -1 if not found and 0 if found so it would look something like:

```
from datetime import datetime
time_str = "10H5M"
if (time_str.find("H") + 1):
    if (time_str.find("M") + 1):
        print(datetime.strptime("10H5M", "%HH%MM").strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    else:
        print(datetime.strptime("10H", "%HH").strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
else:
    print(datetime.strptime("5M", "%MM").strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out an issue in my answer. I've deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
instr = "24H45M"

hour = "00"
minute = "00"
second = "00"
arr = list(instr)
start = 0

for i, char in enumerate(arr):
    if char == "H":
        hour = int(''.join(arr[start:i]))
        start=i+1
    if char == "M":
        minute = int(''.join(arr[start:i]))
        start=i+1
    if char == "S":
        second = int(''.join(arr[start:i]))
        start=i+1

print(f"{hour}:{minute}:{second}")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can user [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to extract numbers and [str.zfill](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_zfill.asp) to add leading zeroes

```
import re


def format_time(s):
    hours = 0
    m = re.search(r'(\d+)H', s)
    if m:
        hours = m.group(1)

    minutes = 0
    m = re.search(r'(\d+)M', s)
    if m:
        minutes = m.group(1)

    seconds = 0
    m = re.search(r'(\d+)S', s)
    if m:
        seconds = m.group(1)

    return f"{str(hours).zfill(2)}:{str(minutes).zfill(2)}:{str(seconds).zfill(2)}"


print(format_time("24H45M"))
print(format_time("35M"))
print(format_time("15M16S"))
```